# Raised border in SVG

Tags: css, svg

I'm attempting create a SVG that expands with the amount of text I enter into it. I have three bars that I'm attempting to wrap with an `outline`, but the bars aren't melding into the outline, I'm getting a raised edge:

[image]

I have create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vx9o14d/1/) with my SVG code, please let me know how I can smooth those borders out. Also, if anyone has a better idea to how to create a SVG button that scales with text, please don't hesitate to let me know!

```css
body { background-color: #13171a; }
g{
  /*g element expands with text child element, so we'll apply the outline here */
  outline: 1px solid #ffdb00;
}
g text { fill: #fff }
```

```html
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
       id="svg2"
       viewBox="0 0 744 1052"
       height="297mm"
       width="210mm">
  <g
     id="layer1">
    
    <path
       id="path4150"
       d="m 70,77 0,45"
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffdb00;stroke-width:6;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
    <path
       id="path4152"
       d="m 85,77 0,45"
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffdb00;stroke-width:6;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;" />
    <path
       id="path4150-6"
       d="m 58,77 0,45"
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffdb00;stroke-width:6;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
    <text
       id="text4169"
       y="113.27509"
       x="101.77287"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       xml:space="preserve"><tspan
         y="113.27509"
         x="101.77287"
         id="tspan4171">TEST TEXT</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: There is a problem with your sample. `outline` is not a valid CSS property for SVG `g` elements.  It should not work. Which browser were you testing on?

Comment: Chrome, I admit I didn't check elsewhere